# Overlay multiple density curves on one plot using lattice in r

Tags: r, lattice

The data that I am working with is **births2006.smpl** from the **nutshell** package. Using the `densityplot()` function in lattice, I was able to produce a graphic that looks like this:[image]

For this I simply used:

```
densityplot( ~ births2006.smpl$DBWT | births2006.smpl$DPLURAL, plot.points=FALSE, xlab="Birth Weight", layout=c(1,5))
```

Now, I am trying to overlay all of these density curves onto one density plot, which I've been assuming it is possible to do with the `densityplot()` function, but after hours of trying with no success I'm not entirely sure. This is the plot that I would like to create:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `groups` argument.

```
library(nutshell)
data(births2006.smpl)

densityplot(~ DBWT, groups = DPLURAL, data = births2006.smpl,
            plot.points = FALSE, xlab = "Birth Weight")
```

[image]